# unable to forward to the error page when any exception is occured

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I am working on springmvc and angular application. When ever some exception occurs I need to forward to the error page, but the below scenario is not forwarding to the error page instead its redirecting to the page but the page is blank and when checked the browser console, below is the exception mentioned:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () :8080/undefined
```

Instead of returning to the page and showing the blank page, I want to forward it to the error page. 
I have a Exception handler class in my exception, any exception is occurred is the handler class is called and it handles and forwards to the error page.

js code:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $sce, MyService, $window) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
         $scope.pdfName = {};
        $scope.html = '';
       MyService.getMyData($scope.id1).then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.myResponse = response;
                //check for error
                if ($scope.myResponse .error) {
                    $rootScope.showError(500, $scope.myResponse .error);
                } else {
                if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                    $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                    //logic here
                    } else {
                    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                    //some logic here}
            }},

        function (errResponse) {
            alert("in error ds");
            $rootScope.showError(500, errResponse);
            $scope.pdfName = {};
         });
    }
    $scope.getMyData();
});
```

//Exception Handler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody  ErrorInfoBean exception(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("In ExceptionControllerAdvice!----  " +e.getMessage());
        ErrorInfoBean error = new ErrorInfoBean();
        error.setStatus(500);
        error.setError(e.getMessage());
        return error;
    }
}
```

From my spring controller when any exception is occurred it is hitting the above MyExceptionControllerAdvice class but not returning the error page.
I tried by changing 500 to 404 in my above MyExceptionControllerAdvice but it didn't worked.

web.xml:
I have configured as below:

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/views/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>404</exception-type>
        <location>/views/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

404 error occur because of page not found or bad url. you are using spring controller and  rest services, so you nee to use request mapping of controller and method. you need to use `@RequestMapping` annotation before class and method.

```
@RequestMapping("/myExceptionClass")
public class

@RequestMapping(value = "/exceptio", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public RestResponse save(){

}
```

so url will be : localhost:8080/projectname/myExceptionClass/exception

Comment: Yes but here my question is something different. If I need to handle 404 how can I redirect it to error page instead of displaying the error in the console and displaying the blank page. I want to show the error.jsp page as I mentioned in the web.xml (mentioned in my above post)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can handle it using http interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $cookies) {
      return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
          if (rejection.status === 404) {
            window.location.href = '/PageNotFound';
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: where do I need to include the interceptor code (in controller or service call)

Comment: Please refer to this link http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/